# What is the difference between “turn off” and “switch off”?

Tags: differences

Are these words interchangeable or it has some restrictions? I mean are these both correct:

```
“Turn off the light.”
“Switch off the light.”
```

Comment: They are interchangeable. "Turn off the light" is a tad more common, however.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Open/switch on the air-conditioner when we are home](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/168848/open-switch-on-the-air-conditioner-when-we-are-home) Also [Turn on vs Switch on,](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/298233/turn-on-vs-switch-on) and [“Turn out the light” vs “Turn off the light”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/56225/turn-out-the-light-vs-turn-off-the-light) and probably others.

Comment: In the narrow sense that you're asking about here they're equivalent. But you don't switch off the highway, for example.

Comment: Telling your girlfriend "That dress is a big switch off" would most likely confuse her.

Comment: You can also end or deactivate things with a *shut off*, *close off*, *cut off*, *toggle off*, and indeed *kill off*, among others.

Answer (score 2):

They are mostly interchangable: for instance you can switch your car off, turn your phone off and so on.

But some people would object if you said "switch off" for a water tap.

Comment: I would. Even if you called it a "faucet". To the OP: we switch electric things on and off, but we can turn off water, gas, etc.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey -  I say “turn off” a lamp when that lamp has a knob that turns.  In fact I say “turn off” for most things electric included.  I don’t say “switch off” very often but when I do it would be for a switch that has a lever-type toggle.  I “shut off” water, gas, etc.

Comment: Let me amend that-  When using the shut-off valve (usually a main supply control) I shut off water and gas.  When using the faucet or the control knob on a torch, I turn off water and gas.

Comment: . . . or object to using *switch* with any electronic device that doesn't have a physical switch (or where one isn't used). Say, for instance, it's on a sensor. Or a push button. Or one of those "clap on / clap off" systems. It's only *switch* (literally) if such a physical object is in place and employed.

Answer (score 0):

Switch off is a more specific form of turn off. You can use turn off for anything, but switch off is generally only used for electronics. The usage likely comes from the [electrical engineering term](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switch):

> The mechanism of a switch removes or restores the conducting path in a circuit when it is operated. It may be operated manually, for example, a light switch or a keyboard button, may be operated by a moving object such as a door, or may be operated by some sensing element for pressure, temperature or flow